# После выполнения gradlew build образовались два jar файла

Tags: java, gradle, jar

После выполнения команд - gradlew clean и затем gradlew build в папке build/libs проекта образовались два jar-файла, один "нормальный", имя "проекта-1.0.8.jar", другой "имя проекта-1.0.8-plain.jar", маленький размером ~ 70 Кб. Что бы это значило?
Код файла build.gradle:

```
    plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.6'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}


group = 'com.progforce'
version = '1.0.8'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    // Spring
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation 'com.github.ulisesbocchio:jasypt-spring-boot-starter:3.0.4'

    // Lombok
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    // Xioma
    //implementation 'com.progforce:xioma:2.0.2'
    // update 24/04/2023
    implementation 'com.progforce:xioma:2.0.3'

    // Sciforma
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'vendor/sciforma')
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```